# atikmdag.sys+127f8 BSOD with ATI Radeon Kernel Mode Driver

Tags: bsod, amd-radeon

Please see this dmp file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdx5cx36dxxpwbz/120413-28704-01.dmp I can't figure out how to solve it. 
My OS is Windows 7 64bit.
Graphics card: ATI Mobility Radeon HD  4670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your extremely old [GPU driver](http://support.amd.com/de-de/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%207%20-%2064), because your one is from 2009:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE (116)
Attempt to reset the display driver and recover from timeout failed.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffa800708e010, Optional pointer to internal TDR recovery context (TDR_RECOVERY_CONTEXT).
Arg2: fffff880058ba7f8, The pointer into responsible device driver module (e.g. owner tag).
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Optional error code (NTSTATUS) of the last failed operation.
Arg4: 0000000000000002, Optional internal context dependent data.

Debugging Details:
------------------


FAULTING_IP: 
atikmdag+127f8
fffff880`058ba7f8 48895c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  GRAPHICS_DRIVER_TDR_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x116

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
dxgkrnl!TdrBugcheckOnTimeout
dxgkrnl!TdrIsRecoveryRequired
dxgmms1!VidSchiReportHwHang
dxgmms1!VidSchiCheckHwProgress
dxgmms1!VidSchiWaitForSchedulerEvents
dxgmms1!VidSchiScheduleCommandToRun
dxgmms1!VidSchiWorkerThread
nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
nt!KxStartSystemThread


IMAGE_NAME:  atikmdag.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x116_IMAGE_atikmdag.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x116_image_atikmdag.sys

    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\atikmdag.sys
    Image name: atikmdag.sys
    Timestamp:        Tue Aug 18 05:05:47 2009
```