# Blue and yellow dots on screen after motherboard replacement

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, gpu, amd-catalyst

I use windows 7 x64 and have a Dell Studio XPS 1645 with a AMD RADEON Mobility HD 4670 video card.

A Dell engineer has replaced the motherboard a week ago after experiencing [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/684130/atikmdag-sys127f8-bsod-with-ati-radeon-kernel-mode-driver). I have updated my AMD Catalyst driver.
The squares appear when I use 3D modelling software but continues in windows.

Here is a printscreen of what I am seeing, the location of the squares keep on changing:

[image]

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: @Xavierjazz How could I fix this problem?

Comment: How do those squares look like? Are they visible on screenshots?

Comment: Appologies, running the dell diagnose tool seems to have fixed the problem. Might have been a driver issue. I will let you know in this thread if it starts again.

Comment: @gronostaj the problem came back, please see printscreen in question.

Comment: This is usually caused by a faulty graphics card, dying graphics card, dirty (overheating) graphics card or underpowered graphics card. I haven't seen such artifacts before relating to driver issues.

Comment: @kobaltz but the engineer has changed the whole motherboard. Could the new one also be faulty with same problem as before?

Comment: It could also be the PCIe Slot or controller on the motherboard. Very possible, but isn't an issue that I've seen before.

Comment: When the motherboard was replaced, did the engineer also replace your memory? Run memtest86+ overnight and see if it picks anything up.

Comment: Name the model? Studio XPS 16 (M1640)?

Comment: @STTR Studio XPS 1645

Comment: @Tog the Dell engineer didn't replace the memory, just the motherboard, hard drive was replaced recently too. Sorry are you talking about the RAM? I will run the test over night.

Answer (score 1):

[Studio XPS 1645](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/studio-xps-1645) driver page.

[Studio XPS 1645 Service Manual and Setup Guide.](http://www.dell.com/support/Manuals/us/en/19/product/studio-xps-1645)

- Save previos BIOS.
- Update BIOS to A13 version.

## - Reboot

- Install Intel Chipset Family driver.

## - Reboot

- Install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package `x86` and `x64` 2005/2008/2010/2012 !

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5638)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18471)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

- Install MSXML 3 SP11, 4 SP3, 6 SP2
- .NET Framework 3.5.1/4/4.5

Reenable .Net 3.5.1 if need:

```
DISM /online /disable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3

DISM /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
```

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Offline Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779)

## - Reboot

- Delete AMD ATI Software, Driver, registry settings.

Delete `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ATI Technologies`

Delete `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Services\ati2mtag`

## - Reboot

- Install DirectX

## - Reboot

- Install  AMD ATI driver

[AMD Catalyst™ Driver for AMD Radeon™ HD 4000, HD 3000 and HD 2000 Series](http://support.amd.com/fr-fr/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%207%20-%2064)

## OR

[Dell lastest AMD Mobility driver version](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/6099/DriverDetails?driverId=RWYXF)